# FlowPanel how to Wrap every given number of components?

Tags: delphi, vcl

is there any way, not that complicated to wrap the components of a FlowPanel for instance every 3 components?

as it works with the property autowrap but by a given amount of controls.

thanks in advance.

Comment: In that case a TGridPanel might be the better choice.

Comment: thing is that I'm using a scrollbox because I need to add many objects to the FlowPanel/Gridpanel and I tried the Gridpanel too but I can't get it to work as good as the FlowPanel because the FlowPanel wraps the controls to a new "Row" pretty clean and I can't seem to get the GridPanel to work as good and I'm making a mess.

Comment: You should explain a little more what controls, what size they have etc. What is the real problem using a `TFlowPanel`? I assume the parent chain is `TForm` - `TScrollBox` - `TFlowPanel` - a variable number of various controls. Are you changing the size (height) of the `TFlowPanel` as you add controls?

Comment: well @TomBrunberg, the controls I add to the FlowPanel are Timage, they are autosized to their real dimensions so the size varies from image to image. the real problem I'm having is that if I add 2 big images the panel may wrap the third on a new "Row" which is ok, but if I add 4 small images they may fit in a single row, but I don't want that to happen, I would like the panel to wrap the fourth little image on a new "Row" even if it fits. the parent chain you say is right. the panel is aligned to the top and set to autosize as well, I'm not changing it's size manually. thanks for commenting.

Comment: Thanks for additional info. But surely you must imagine some limits for the image sizes, no? So what is the (max) width of the `TFlowpanel`? what are the max and min widths of the images?

Comment: the max width of the TFlowPanel is 1330 and, for the images as they are "previews" for label printing here is were it gets tricky, normally they go from 300 to 400 but that is for my printer, If the customers use a bigger label printer that allows bigger sizes then the images should be bigger. but as of now the images tend to go from 100 to 400 width.

Comment: Ok, you posted a comment while I was busy preparing the answer. The widths I speak about in my answer look strange now that I know the actual measures, but I'm sure can grasp the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You left the actual image sizes open, so here its the general idea with some example sizes that you will have to adopt to your liking. I made some initial tests with buttons (normal width = 75), so I sized the `TFlowPanel` to 235 px wide.

The idea is to have a `TFlowPanel` with a fixed width (`Constraints.MaxWidth = 235; Constraints.MinWidth = 235;`) but `AutoSize=True` so it can grow downward. If you add e.g. 75px wide components, 3 of them fit perfectly on one row. If wider, only 2 or even only 1 fit on a row. So far as you wish. But if the width is only 56px (mean value) or less the number of compnents will be four or more.

I suggest a solution to place such a smaller component on a panel of its own, with a width of 75px, and that panel on the `TFlowPanel`. Thus no more than three components will fit on one row.

This is the code with which a number of buttons were placed on a `TFlowPanel`.

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  btn: TButton;
  pan: TPanel;
begin
  inc(count);
  btn := TButton.Create(self);
  btn.Width := random(60)+35;
  if btn.Width < 75 then
  begin
    pan := TPanel.Create(self);
    pan.Width := 75;
    pan.Height := 30;
    pan.BevelOuter := bvNone;
    btn.Parent := pan;
    pan.Parent := FlowPanel1;
  end
  else
  begin
    btn.Parent := FlowPanel1;
  end;
  btn.Caption := IntToStr(count);
end;
```

And the end result

[image]

---

**Alternative solution**

Another solution (since you mentioned `TImage`s) is to always create the `TImage`s with a **width of at least 75px**. The picture (if smaller than that) can be centered in the `TImage`, if you like. This is based on the fact that the image doesn't affect the size of the `TImage` control (unless you want it to).

Also, if you don't really absolutely need to show the images in their full actual size, you can set the `Proportional` property `true`. From the docs:

> When Proportional is true, images that are too large to fit in the image control are scaled down (while maintaining the same aspect ratio) until they fit in the image control.